# HTML/CSS - Hiding part of an image source

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, src

What would be the best and most correct way of hiding part of an image source in an img tag

Say I have the following:

```
<img alt="" src="myimage.jpg" class="photo" />
```

My target is to have the image enclosed in a rounded corner container, which will obviously cover the corners of image at the top.

Should I just go and put an absolute positioned element on top of the image as if you're putting a cut-out paper on top of a photo or is there some kind of alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intention is that the image gets rounded corners, you could just use `border-radius` on it. If you need the container to have the rounded corners and that the image gets clipped, use `overflow: hidden` for it.

You can find a demonstration for it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/hwDYV/

What you want is something similar to this

```
<div class="contact">
    <img src=http://jsfiddle.net/img/top-bg.png /><a href="#">Username</a>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
DIV.contact {background: silver; border-radius: 8px; margin: 10px auto 0 5px; width: 200px; text-align: center; overflow: hidden}
DIV.contact IMG {display: block; width: 100%; }
```

Note that the image is just a blue rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

- Process the images server side to apply the transformation.
- Overlay an absolutely positioned mask image on top of the images.
- Use some clever CSS with rounded corners and absolutely positioned transparent elements to achieve the same effect as the mask image.

Comment: I was thinking about setting a background-image to the img but then released that it would go behind the image defined in the source :/

I'm trying to eliminate image processing. The target of this site is to be a forum like setup where people upload their images to their profile.